# How to detect a certain increment in a for-loop without a separate variable?

Tags: c#, for-loop

Basically, every time in a `for/loop` how do you know when you hit a certain increment?

A way to do is to use a second variable as a counter, like this:

```
int i2 = 0;
for(int i=0;i<70;i++){
  if(i2==7){ i2=0; @Model.Value  }  
  i2++;
}
```

This writes `@Model.Value` once for every 7 times it loops.

Is there a way to avoid using a second variable (`i2`)--A shorthand way to do something like this?

Comment: in your example, you might want to increment `i2` BEFORE the `if` statement, otherwise the first output will be on the eighth iteration, not the seventh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [modular arithmetic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6zfzfy7(v=vs.90).aspx):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++)
{
    if (i % 7 == 0)
        // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use the modulus operator, which returns the remainder after doing a division operation. Since you want it to happen every seventh iteration, you would use `% 7`. Since your index is starting at zero, you also want to add `1` to `i` when doing the division, or else it will start on your eighth iteration (when `i` is seven).

```
for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++)
{
    if((i + 1) % 7 == 0) @Model.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this format

```
 for (;;) 
     statement;
```

In your example you would accomplish your task by writing:

```
for (int iii = 0; iii < 70; iii++){
   if (iii % 7 == 0) 
   (@Model.Value)
   }
```

Comment: you also never declare the vairiable `i` that you use in the condition (you declare `iii`).